401 Unauthorized Error with Elevenlabs API in Production Environment
I am facing an issue with the Elevenlabs Text-to-Speech API. While I am able to get a response via the API on my local server, I encounter a 401 Unauthorized error in the production environment. I have thoroughly tested everything, including verifying that the API key and environment variable names are correct. My app is deployed on Render.
The app has been deployed for five months, and I did not face this issue until recently. A few months ago, I could get API responses on both the local and deployed versions. Even after redeploying to previous versions where everything was working fine, I am still encountering the same issue.
What could be the possible reason for this, and how can I fix it?
I have thoroughly tested everything, including verifying that the API key and environment variable names are correct.

I was running into this EXACT issue. I had my API deployed on Render and it was working great for months, then suddenly, the same time you experienced this issue, all my Elevenlabs requests were coming back with a 401 error from my Render deployment. Locally, everything worked fine. After trying a million different ways to confirm my API key was loading from the env correctly and being sent correctly in the request, I eventually just decided to deploy my backend API somewhere else. I added a simple Dockerfile to my repo and just deployed it on Google Cloud Run and now everything is working fine. It looks like Elevenlabs is rejecting requests made from Render IP addresses for some reason. Not sure why, but I hope this helps. Google Cloud Run is super duper easy to use  and has free tiers so, try that out and see if it fixes your issue like it did for me.

Thank you so much for your helpful response! I really appreciate you sharing your experience. In my case, the issue was resolved after I reached out to Elevenlabs' support team. They confirmed that the problem occurred because I was on the free plan. As soon as I upgraded to a paid plan, everything worked smoothly again, including my deployment on Render.
Thanks again for your assistance!
